# -webkit-transform not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css, vendor-prefix

I've found that `-webkit-transform: rotateZ(10deg);` doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9. What can be used instead of that using CSS3?

Comment: That'll only work on webkit browsers like chrome and safari. Most of the browser engines have specific prefixes for tags to just apply to them, like -o for Opera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `-ms-transform:rotateZ(10deg);`?

As `-webkit`is also a vendor specific prefix, you'll have to add those for non-webkit browsers, too.

(like `-ms`, `-moz`, `-o`)

Check out this CSS3 3D Transforms Tutorial for more info:
http://www.pageresource.com/css3/3d-transforms-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

3D transforms don't work in IE9. IE10 does support them, though.

Here's a chart of supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/transforms3d[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use ***2D transforms*** in ie9 - i.e. :

```
-ms-transform: rotate(25deg);
```